# .ajax not functioning in an event handler

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Can anyone help with this? I can't seem to find any problems with my codes. It seems like my view cannot go to the ReplacementDriverListDatabase.php
Below is my view

```
@section('libraries')
@parent
{!!Html::script('bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.1-dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::style('bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.1-dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')!!}
{!!Html::script('jonthornton-jquery-timepicker-fb09cd8/jquery.timepicker.js')!!}
{!!Html::style('jonthornton-jquery-timepicker-fb09cd8/jquery.timepicker.css')!!}
{!!Html::script('jonthornton-Datepair.js-efff9ba/dist/datepair.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('jonthornton-Datepair.js-efff9ba/dist/jquery.datepair.js')!!}
@stop
<div class="input-daterange form-group" id="datepicker">
{!! Form::text('replacementStartDate',NULL,['class'=>'input-sm form-control','id'=>'start','name'=>'replacementStartDate']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('currentDriver','Current Driver') !!}
    {!!  Form::text('currentDriverList', NULL,['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'currentDriv']) !!}
</div>
@section("script")
<script>
  $("#start").select(function(){
    test(); 
    });
  function test(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '../resources/views/ReplacementDriverListDatabase.php',
            async: false,
            dataType:   "json", // <== JSON-P request
            success:    function(data){
                $.each(data.driverList, function(key, value){ // <=== Note, `data.results`, not just `data`
                $("#currentDriv").val('aaa');
                });
            }
  });
};
</script>
@stop
```

The next part is my ReplacementDriverListDatabase.php

```
<?php


 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "bustracking";


 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 $query = "SELECT driverNickName FROM driver";
 $result = $conn->query($query);

 $numberOfRow = $result->num_rows;

 $driverList["driverList"] = array();
 if ($numberOfRow > 0) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dataRow = array();
    $dataRow['driverNickName'] = $row['driverNickName'];

    array_push($driverList["driverList"], $dataRow);
 }
 $result->free();
  }

 echo(json_encode($driverList));

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

It does not show any errors when i am testing it. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use document.ready event

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("#start").select(function(){
    test(); 
    });    
});
```

Comment: thx for your reply, but it still can't work, it seems like the select event handler can proceed to test() but the $.ajax cannot work.

Comment: Use error event to catch error
 
`function test(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '../resources/views/ReplacementDriverListDatabase.php',
            async: false,
            dataType:   "json", // <== JSON-P request
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data.driverList, function(key, value){ // <=== Note, `data.results`, not just `data`
                $("#currentDriv").val('aaa');
                });
            },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message);
   }
  });
}; `

Comment: it shows SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 @Asim

Comment: Look like you are receiving HTML from the server, but `dataType: json` is telling jQuery to parse it as JSON which is causing this error.
Use **console** to see what response you are receiving @Alex

Comment: by removing the dataType: json, and under success: function (data) i added in console.log(data) but it shows the source code of it... anything gone wrong? @Asim